# Why the sizeof character constant is 4 bytes?

Tags: c, sizeof

The program below produces

> output - 1 4 4

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char ch;
    ch='A'; 
    printf("%d %d %d\n",sizeof(ch),sizeof('A'),sizeof(3.2f));

}
```

Why is the size of character constant is 4 bytes ?

Comment: Because `int` on your platform has 4 bytes.

Comment: C character literals are `sizeof(int)` large. C++ character literals are `sizeof(char)` large. It's not constant `4`, it's `sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 4):

Because according to the C standard the type of a character constant is `int`, and not `char`.

So in effect, this is the `sizeof(int)` on your platform.

Comment: Detail: According to the C standard, there are 2 kinds of literals: _string literal_ and _compound literal_.  `'A'` is not identified as a literal but a  _character constant_.

Comment: @chux - Thanks. This sort of inconsistency in the standards use of English is killing me sometimes.

Comment: Maybe it is not so much an English inconsistency as C is differentiating a _literal_, which can have an address  `printf("%p\n", (void*) &"abc");`, from a _constant_, which cannot: `printf("%p\n", (void*) & 'a');`

Comment: @chux - Now that you spell it out, I suppose there is room to differentiate.

Answer (score 2):

ch is char type so 1 byte.

'A' is int type so 4 bytes. Because in C the character constant is an int type.

Last is float value so 4 bytes.

These values according to the machine you are using.

> Edit -

The range of int and float depends on the machine you are using, 16 bit int is as common as 32 bit int.

Comment: yes, this is the answer he is looking for. 'A' is converted to `int`

Comment: Nothing is "converted". A character literal *is of type* `int`.

Comment: I'm not sure about the use of the word "converted" here. Wouldn't it be more accurate to say that it *is* an `int` (and when you do `ch = 'A';` the `int` is converted to `char`)?

Comment: Sorry my mistake.

Comment: You don't make clear that the standard types lack a fixed size except for `char`, which is always one byte. "so" isn't any better because you cannot draw the conclusion "`int`, so it's four bytes."

Comment: There is no guarantee `int` has 4 bytes, nor for `float`.

Comment: @Olaf I am answering according to platform he is using.